# Converting number in string with negative sign at the end

Tags: c#, numbers

From the MSDN documentation I should use **NumberFormatInfo**'s **NumberNegativePattern** property to set the expected pattern for negative number values.

So I tried:

```
var format = new NumberFormatInfo {NumberNegativePattern = 3};
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble("1.000-", format));
```

But I always receive a **FormatException** saying "Input string was not in a correct format.". I also tried formatting with **NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo** - with same results.

Comment: en-US so the actual value is -1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a format here - it looks like the `NumberNegativePattern` is only used when formatting, not parsing, and then only for the `N` format. However, there's a `NumberStyles` value for this:

```
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("1.000-", 
    NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `NumberFormatInfo`'s `NumberNegativePattern` assigned to 3 but the other properties of your `NumberFormatInfo` will be depends on your `CurrentCulture`. But that's not the point there.

This `Convert.ToDouble(String, IFormatProvider)` method [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#5c0d698e0861e80a) as;

```
public static double ToDouble(String value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return 0;
    return Double.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

and [`Double.Parse(String, IFormatProvider)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#73cc31e0b47fd637) implemented as;

```
public static double Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
{
   return Parse(s, NumberStyles.Float| NumberStyles.AllowThousands, NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider));
}
```

And [`NumberStyles.Float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.NumberStyles.aspx) doesn't have `NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign`, that's why your code throws [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.formatexception.aspx).

It is really hard to tell your `1.000` value is `1` with decimal point or `1000` with thousand separator, but you can use `AllowDecimalPoint` or `AllowThousands` styles with `AllowTrailingSign` style as a second parameter of [`Double.Parse(String, NumberStyles)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).